# If condition in windows registry file

Tags: windows, registry

I want to check if a key exists in the registry, and, if so, add a new entry. As an example:

```
IF [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySoftware]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\]
"name"="my name"
ENDIF
```

I don't want to use *.bat files or any other scripting. Is there a way to do this **using only** a `*.reg` file?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but .REG files don't support conditional operations such as "IF".
All it supports is adding and deleting keys

Microsoft Documentation on the humble reg file
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516